# why does numpy.dot is fault for numpy.dot(a,b) but has output for numpy.dot(b,a)?

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to understand why numpy's dot function behaves as it does:

```
t1 = np.array( [1, 0] )
t2 = np.array( [ [7,6],
                 [7,6],
                 [7,6],
                 [7,6]] )
```

**np.dot(t1, t2)** is fault because of wrong matrix multiplication:

> ValueError: shapes (2,) and (4,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 4 (dim 0)

this is right. I can understand it. But why does **np.dot(t2, t1)** has output instead of the same fault with **np.dot(t1, t2)**? The different order of parameters is interpreted differently.

> [7 7 7 7]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

Function raises ValueError:

If the last dimension of a is not the same size as the second-to-last dimension of b.

Notice you are not only working with 1D arrays:

```
In [6]: t1.ndim
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: t2.ndim
Out[7]: 2
```

So, `t2` is a 2D array.
You also see this in the output of `t2.shape`: (4,2) indicates two dimensions as (2,) is one dimension.

The behaviour of `np.dot` is different for 1D and 2D arrays (from the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)):

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D
>   arrays to inner product of vectors

That is the reason you get different results, because you are mixing 1D and 2D arrays. Since `t2` is a 2D array, `np.dot(b, a)` tries a matrix multiplication and `np.dot(a, b)` tries inner product, which fails.

In matrix multiplication case (refer [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul)): second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the appended 1 is removed. In simple words, t2 shape is (4,2) and t1 shape is (2,). t1 is 1D, shape of t1 is converted to (2,1) and after matrix multiplication 1 is removed. Hence, if you will store output of dot product, you can check shape will be (4, ).

```
t = np.dot(t2,t1)
t.shape

t.shape
Out[57]: (4,)
```

Comment: You seems doesn't understand my question. Why does the different order  of parameters be interpreted differently?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative, by definition.

Comment: Thanks @Sayali Sonawane.  np.dot(t1, t2) is the 1-D array multiplying with 2-D array. It's matrix multiplication which fails. This is correct;   np.dot(t2, t1) is the 2-D array (4*2) multiplying with 1-D array(1*2).  This doesn't fail. Why?

Comment: if 1D array multiply with 2D array, the 1D array will always be treated as column vector automatically by numpy?

Comment: In matrix multiplication case: second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the appended 1 is removed. In simple words, t2 shape is (4,2) and t1 shape is (2,). t1 is 1D, shape of t1 is converted to (2,1) and after matrix multiplication 1 is removed. Hence, if you will store output of dot product, you can check  shape will be (4, ).

Comment: It's the rule what I looked for. Thanks.